# How to rehup sshd process?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have followed instructions from

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-digitalocean-droplets

But my terminal looks like

```
ps auxw | grep ssh
milenko  21891  0.0  0.0  21292   924 pts/4    S+   16:24   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

Should I `kill 21891`?
What does grep --color auto stand for?Can someone elaborate more om this?

Comment: Don't kill it - grep is a search utility.  You take the output of ps (which shows processes running) then pipe (send) it into grep which takes out any line that doesn't match "ssh".  Grep will always show up.  Basically, you found no 'ssh' processes running - but did find your grep looking for ssh processes.
The grep will be finished once you see the output, so it'll be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep --color=auto` is the `grep` from the line above. When you would try to kill it later, it will no longer be there, because the above command ended.

The reason why the line does not list only `grep ssh` is, that you have alias for `grep` to be nicely colored:

```
$ which grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    /usr/bin/grep
```

TLDR what is going on there: Your `sshd` server is not running.